# buttons overflow in header bar jquerymobile phonegap?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating a mobile app for android with jquerymobile and phonegap. I have few buttons on header. Still header looks very thin and the button jumps out of the header bar. How can I make the button fit inside the header bar and make header bar looks bigger?

Also, how can I make the button icons appear in the application?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: no I could not. Then, I implemented it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some thing like this

```
<button type="button" class="ui-btn-left"
            data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="b">Button name</button>
```

in the header section of the page.
I did not test on android but works fine on iPhone

Comment: It makes the header big. But including the header, the button is overlapped by the content below it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that simply adding `overflow: auto;` to the heading wrapper will solve the issue.